# create flat file in ssis package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on creating a csv export from a SQL Server database and I've been familiar with a process for doing so that admittedly, I've never completely understood.  The process involves creating a "template" file, which defines the columns and structure for the file export.  Once the "template" file exists, you can use a Data Flow task to fill it and a File System Task to copy it to the final storage destination with whatever file name you'd like (frequently a date/time stamp).

Is there a reason that you can't simply create a file directly, without the intermediate "template" file?  I've looked around for a bit and it seems like all the proposed solutions involve connecting to an existing file.  I see that there is a "Create File" Usage type for a "File" connection manager, but you can't use it in any File System Task.  The only File System Type connection managers you can use relative to a file are "Copy", "Delete", "Move", "Rename", and "Set Attributes".

Is there a way to create a file at package run time and fill it?

Comment: You can do it with a script transformation.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of SSIS is to create a data flow with metadata so that the data can be manipulated - if you just want to go database direct to CSV you are probably better off using bcp (bulk copy program) from the command line. If you want to include it as part of a SSIS package just add an Execute Process Task and add the command line to that. You can dynamically change the included columns or the output file by adding an expression to the task. You could also call bcp though TSQL using an Excute SQL Task.

One other option is to concatenate all your columns in your query inter-spaced with a comma literal and output to a text file with just one very wide column.

For documentation on bcp look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms162802.aspx)